# product.carousel not showing for anonymous viewers

Tags: plone

I'm having a weird issue with product.carousel not displaying for anon users. When logged into my Plone site, I can see the carousel just fine. The moment I log out, it's gone. The workflow is set to single_state so it publishes automatically. I've also double checked to make sure each carousel banner is 'Published'...still no luck.

I'm on Plone 4.2.1.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: please provide the relevant pieces of code

Comment: Sounds like something is still unpublished. Can you check if carousel is in HTML code or hidden by CSS? Something could interfere with carousel show up.

Comment: Also if you can repeat the problem with clean Plone installation you can file a bug against Products.Carousel. However it is popular addon and many users are using it daily, so problems like this should be catched and fixed, so it is most likely some issue specific to your system.

Comment: Thanks guys. It appeared every time on a new install on my development server, so it is definitely something on the production server.  I ended up finding collective.easyslider and got that up and running without any issues. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Can you click close on yor question, then? TIA.

Comment: OK, how do I close a question?